# Any way to use Firebase google authentication in expo (create-react-native-app) without "eject" project

Tags: firebase, google-authentication, google-play-services, expo, create-react-native-app

As the question, for Login with google in firebase need to set google-service but if you create new react-native project with create-react-native-app there will have no "android" or "ios" folder (accept used "eject") so, anyone have a suggestion for me?
However I've no idea for how to setting google-service in my project too (even I "eject" the project).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't necessary to make any changes to the android or ios folders in order to support Google sign in with firebase on an app built with Expo.

1. Follow [the guide for configuring Google auth on the Expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google)
2. Use the approach described in Expo's [Using Firebase guide](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-firebase#tying-sign-in-providers-with-firebase), where it describes how to authenticate with Facebook, and swap out Google where needed.

Comment: It's work pretty well to login to google and get username or email but cannot accessToken to firebase with error "Unable to parse Google id_token?
Please what is wrong
` code` `googleAuthenticate = (token) => {
    const provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
    provider.addScopes('profile');
    provider.addScopes('email');
    const credential = provider.credential(token)
    return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
  }; `

Comment: @NoerNova - with the response that you get back from Expo's api you have an object with `idToken`, `accessToken` and some other properties (https://github.com/expo/expo-sdk/blob/d152d47f240aadc1618e13a2ab3832411c62e9b8/src/Google.js#L18-L36) -- you need to take the `idToken` and `accessToken` and pass them into your `googleAuthenticate` function like so: https://gist.github.com/brentvatne/46449731ae852a14ce321e14f0f19187

Comment: I recorded a coding session where Firebase auth is integrated to an expo project via the Firebase web sdk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TlOhmdl3-M.

Answer (score 20):

@brentvatne 's answer is a bit out of date.  Here's how I got it working on Expo v27

Important bit:  you can get your client ids with [these instructions](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google#go-to-the-credentials-page).

Just select your firebase app from the project dropdown on the google page.

```
const _loginWithGoogle = async function() {
  try {
    const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({
      androidClientId:"YOUR_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID",
      iosClientId:"YOUR_iOS_CLIENT_ID",
      scopes: ["profile", "email"]
    });

    if (result.type === "success") {
      const { idToken, accessToken } = result;
      const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken, accessToken);
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
        .then(res => {
          // user res, create your user, do whatever you want
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("firebase cred err:", error);
        });
    } else {
      return { cancelled: true };
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err:", err);
  }
};
```